# Audiokit.Table not displaying after updating to AudioKit5

Tags: audiokit

I recently updated to AudioKit5 off of the v5-main branch. After doing so, I noticed that my AK Table View is no longer displaying the table but instead is display a black background. Below is the code I am using to display the table view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var waveformView: NSView!
...

...

let width = self.waveformView.frame.width
let height = self.waveformView.frame.height
    
    do {
        if let url = Utils.getUrlForSample(sample:sample) {
            let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
            if let table = AudioKit.Table(file:file) {
                let a = AudioKit.TableView(table, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
                self.waveformView.addSubview(a)
            }
            
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: That is odd. We're about to change the plotting anyway, so perhaps this will be fixed soon. If you find a fix first, make sure to make a pull request.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Sounds great, will do.